# Detect if .pkpass is already added to Google Wallet

Tags: android, google-wallet

I have an app which offers users to add a pass into their Google Wallet using a banner on home screen. There is a requirement that when user adds this pass to the wallet then the app should hide this banner.

I cant find an API that would let me check if a specific `.pkpass` already exists in user's wallet. Can you guys help? maybe there is a library that can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Google Wallet passes are JSON files, not PKPASS.

But you can perform a GET request, and then generate a ViGW button with the pass link attached.

https://developers.google.com/wallet/generic/rest/v1/genericclass/get#http-request

Link template: `https://pay.google.com/gp/v/object/{<issuerId>}.{<objectId>}`

Comment: can you clarify how Google Wallet passes are not PKPASS? On the app I work there is a website that opens, which downloads .pkpass file and then it is opened in Google Wallet. 

Also I dont get it from where I should get issuerId or objectId to create a request, should not it also need someking of userId? how it will differentiate for which wallet is the request?

Comment: my bad, the link used in the app downloads .pkpass or redirects to Google Pay based on where I open it... So yes, those passes are not PKPASS

Comment: If you open the Google Pay & Wallet Console you'll find your Issuer and Object IDs.